# aws serverless spring boot set up is failing

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, servlet-container

here is my setup below,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.amazonaws.serverless.sample.springboot.controller")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

public class LambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LambdaHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        if (handler == null) {
            try {
                handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);

            } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                outputStream.close();
                return;
            }
        }

        AwsProxyRequest request = mapper.readValue(inputStream, AwsProxyRequest.class);

        AwsProxyResponse resp = handler.proxy(request, context);
        mapper.writeValue(outputStream, resp);
        // just in case it wasn't closed by the mapper
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

each time when when I am trying invoke my lambda  from local console using command - "serverless invoke local -f hello" I am getting below exception,

j

```
ava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.serverless.InvokeBridge.invoke(InvokeBridge.java:102)
        at com.serverless.InvokeBridge.<init>(InvokeBridge.java:40)
        at com.serverless.InvokeBridge.main(InvokeBridge.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:167)
        at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:77)
        at com.techprimers.serverless.services.AWSLambdaHandler.handleRequest(AWSLambdaHandler.java:172)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 23 more
```

at line - "handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);"

Please HELP me resolve this, I tried various ways of boot setup with aws lambda but failed every time. Please help me fix this or help me out in setting up in any other way. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Farhan, I have the same issue but i have everything correct looks like. can you pls help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577207/spring-boot-deployed-in-lambda-throws-nosuchmethoderror

Answer (score 4):

In your logs we can see :

No**Class**DefFoundError: **javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer**
**ClassNotFound**Exception: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer

Could you please check if libs are loaded , there must be something missing and not loaded up correctly

Also, something like this has been done

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also double check steps in :
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot

Comment: I see all lot of libraries loaded properly, can you please help me with the name of library which you think is not loaded ?

Comment: I have rechecked the dependencies, and the one you mentioned above was also there already.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue but i have everything correct looks like. can you pls help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577207/spring-boot-deployed-in-lambda-throws-nosuchmethoderror

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using version 0.2 of aws-serverless-java-container-spring and had to switch to version 1.3.2 as the former version didn't have SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler class.

Comment: Hi @SagarJaspal I have the same issue but i have everything correct looks like. can you pls help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577207/spring-boot-deployed-in-lambda-throws-nosuchmethoderror